# What is the difference between $D^{(s_{+},s_{-})}(\Lambda)$ and $D^{(s_{-},s_{+})}(\Lambda)$?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory

I’m studying QFT and confused about the difference between $D^{(s_{+},s_{-})}(\Lambda)$ and $D^{(s_{-},s_{+})}(\Lambda)$.

For example, when we make the vector representation, we don’t take $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$ but $D^{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}(\Lambda)$. This is because (1) $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$ is $4 \rightarrow 4$, and (2) $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$ become $D^ {(0,\frac{3}{2})}(\Lambda) $ under the parity inversion. I understand (1), but I can’t understand what is the matter of (2). Both $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$ and $D^ {(0,\frac{3}{2})}(\Lambda) $ are decomposed to $D^{(\frac{3}{2})}(\Lambda)$, so I feel they are almost same.

I know $s_{\pm}$ is a spin number of $J_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2} (L\pm iM)$, so $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$ means $J_{+}^{z}\rightarrow3/2, J_{-}^{z}\rightarrow 0 $ and $D^ {(0,\frac{3}{2})}(\Lambda) $  means $J_{+}^{z}\rightarrow 0, J_{-}^{z}\rightarrow 3/2$, but I cannot understand why is $D^ {(0,\frac{3}{2})}(\Lambda) $ not equivalent to $D^{(\frac{3}{2},0)}(\Lambda)$.

Can anyone help me?

References:

1. Zee’ s Group theory in a nutshell, p.458.
2. Weinberg’ s QFT section 5.7 of volume 1.

Comment: Check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Finite-dimensional_representations), which goes into some detail about left vs right handed representations of the Lorentz group.

Comment: There is not direct answer to my question, but I could come to the answer that $D^{(s_{1},s_{2})}$ is not equivalent to $D^{(s_{1},s_{2})*}$ when we think Lorentz boost, by some calculation. Thank you!